# Может ли создавать нагрузку на сервер MobileDetect.php?

Tags: php

Есть популярная библиотека для определения типа устройства [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/). 
Может ли она создавать нагрузку на сервер, и по какому принципу она работает?

Comment: принцип работы вроде очевиден должен быть, что собственно и указано на сайте библиотеки _"It uses the `User-Agent` string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment."_

Comment: Я наверное неправильно выразился. Больше интересует, нагружает ли такая библиотека сервер, когда определяет тип устройства, или нагрузка практически неощутима?

Comment: все относительно. но маловероятно, что вы заметите хоть какую-то разницу.

Comment: По теме https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/issues/140